# How to tail dmesg on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, terminal, logs, tail, dmesg

In a CentOS 7 server, I typed `dmesg` and noted the time stamp of the last entry.

Next, I typed `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` in a DIFFERENT TERMINAL ON THE SAME MACHINE, so that I could watch the log tail.

Third, I ran some scripts on the same machine using the same terminal.  Nothing changed in the terminal in which I had typed `tail -f /var/log/dmesg`.

Finally, I typed `dmesg` again, extracted the log into Notepad++, and noticed that over 1,500 lines of new logs had been created in the `dmesg` output while I was running the other scripts.

**What specific commands must be typed in order to get the `tail` of the `dmesg` logs to actually display on the screen?**

Comment: I was mistaken; I had forgotten that dmesg is a ring buffer.  CentOS 7 _might_ have `dmesg -w` or `dmesg --follow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dmesg is a ring buffer.  Which is to say, when it reaches a certain size, old data are thrown out.  Because of this, it doesn't really work like a normal file.  It's kind of like the data in `/proc` - when you `cat` or otherwise display it, you see only the state at that instant.

To get around this, newer implementations of `dmesg` include the `-w` or `--follow` switches, which work effectively like `tail -f`.  If you want to capture this into a conventional file rather than a ring buffer, you can use a construct such as:

```
dmesg --follow >> /path/to/file
```

Or, if you wish to also see what is being captured:

```
dmesg --follow | tee -a /path/to/file
```

As with `tail -f`, this can be terminated with a simple INT signal or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.