# How to check for network issues? dmesg? and how to setup logging?

Tags: networking, logs, dmesg

I'm pretty new to Linux but have worked with Windows servers and networks for 30 years so I understand the principles but am learning the 'Linux' way of doing things.

I have setup a Centos 7.6 server that acts a Linux repository for Veeam backups. I am currently working working with their tech support on an issue where it appears that their software is losing its network connection to the repository. This could be an issue with their software or a networking problem. I am pretty confident that our network is fine so I want to check if there are any network issues on the Centos Server itself (I'm using an Intel 710x 10Gb NIC with the built in Centos drivers).

From what I have read, I should be checking dmesg. If I am incorrect or there is a better way please let me know.

I have found this post [How to tail dmesg on CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354627/how-to-tail-dmesg-on-centos-7?newreg=e6360f6817d64698a8b5e0ae295c288b) that gets me started but have a couple of questions specific to our environment.

Our server is only powered on for a few hours a night. If I use `dmesg --follow >> /path/to/file` will this persist between reboots? If not how do I achieve this?

Assuming that it isn't persistent and I have to implement a way to have the command run at each reboot, is there a way to automatically use the date in the filename so I get a new file for each day?

Finally, I haven't tried logging to a file yet but looking at the output of dmesg, all the timings seem to be relative to the boot time. Is there a way to have the actual system time in the log output?

Comment: welcome to Unix and U&L, system messages (`dmesg`'s and other are stored in `/var/log/messages`, so no need to invent hot water. You have networking problem with a host only powered a few hours at night ? Am I reading well ?

Comment: Thanks for that Archemar. I was unaware that dmesg's messages got recorded in /var/log/messages. I don't believe that I do have networking problems but the Veeam software reports "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)" so we are looking for reasons this is happening and I need to confirm there are no network problems.Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Both /var/log/messages and SSH debug logs show no issues.